# Finding the correct input_shape for Conv1d input layer

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm currently trying to run a model with a conv1d layer as the input. And I think my issue is with the input_shape value.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(100,), kernel_size=5, filters=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(units=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_vec, y_train_encoded, epochs=10 , batch_size=64)
```

*ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_27 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 1, 100)*

x_vec.shape = (52579, 100)

I thought my input_shape was supposed to be the input shape for a single input, which would be (100,). Is that wrong, and if so why is it wrong?

Comment: Input should be 3d

Answer (score 1):

### Changes to the Conv layer

The `input_shape` argument for a convolutional layer should be at least 2 numbers. Depending on the `data_format`, it should be either: (SPATIAL_DIM, NUM_CHANNELS) or (NUM_CHANNELS, SPATIAL_DIM), where `SPATIAL_DIM` is your sequence length (or time steps), and the `NUM_CHANNELS` is the number of channels in the input (or input dimensionality).

In your case there are two viable solutions:

```py
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(100, 1), kernel_size=5, filters=100, activation='relu'))
# THE REST IS THE SAME
```

or

```py
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(1, 100), kernel_size=5, filters=100, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(data_format='channels_first'))
# THE REST IS THE SAME
```

### Changes to the Pooling layer

Notice that in the second example you have to give the `MaxPool1D` the same data_format. Otherwise, the max pooling will happen over the channels, which is not what you are trying to do (is it?).

### Changes to the input

Given that the convolutional layer expect very specific input format (see [this](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/) for details), you cannot just use your input. Firstly, I am assuming your input has only a single channel, meaning your input has shape `(N, SPATIAL_DIM)`, where N is the batch size, and the `SPATIAL_DIM` is the length of each sample. In that case you must reshape the input into `(N, SPATIAL_DIM, 1)` to tell the model that there is only one channel in the input:

```py
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Reshape((100, 1), input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=5, filters=100, activation='relu'))
# THE REST IS THE SAME
```

### Your fixed model

```py
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Reshape((100, 1), input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=5, filters=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(units=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_vec, y_train_encoded, epochs=10 , batch_size=64)
```

### How to avoid such problems and where to go next

When writing the models / training them it is very important to understand the variables that are being used when computing the shapes. This is especially important for the convolutional layers.

I would encourage you to read through the API for each layer. For example you can get the API info foc Conv1d here:

- [Keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/)
- [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html)

Once you do that you can ask questions in the very specialized forums:

- [Keras](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/c/special-interest-groups/keras/16/none)
- [PyTorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/)

Comment: Ok so a few questions. First, can you explain what you mean by SPATIAL_DIM and NUM_CHANNELS. And second, I tried both solutions and they game ne the following error:     ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 100). And I'm not really sure what to make of it. I'd love to hear any other ideas if you have them.

Comment: The reason you are getting the error, because your input has to have channels. Note that the convolutional layers expect the inputs to be "channeled", which means you have to reshape the input into `(N, NUM_CHANNELS, L)`. I will put more explanation in the answer in a sec